# How to generalise an adapter class in Java

Tags: java, adapter

I have started learning Java and I came across `Adapter` class. I am trying to use one adapter class for two of my frame classes like below. Is it possible to generalise this adapter class, so many other classes can use this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;

public class FrameAdopter extends WindowAdapter {
    SampleFrame sf;
    SampleFrame01 sf1;
    FrameAdopter(SampleFrame sf) {
        this.sf=sf; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean generify  FrameAdopter  so you can essentially supply any SampleFrame  class ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, you can generify like the following

```
public class MyClass<T extends Frame> extends WindowAdapter
{
  T frame;
  public MyClass(T frame)
  {
    this.frame = frame;
  }
}
```

or in your case

```
public class FrameAdopter<T extends SampleFrame> extends WindowAdapter
{
  T sf;
  public FrameAdopter(T sf)
  {
    this.sf= sf;
  }
}
```